# Why is array.splice removing the last element always?

Tags: javascript

I have this code here

```
 cart.splice(1, 1);
```

where cart is an array. No matter what I give inside the first element of splice it always removes the last element. How to fix it and why is it happening?
My array looks like this:-

```
[{
  "productId": "400002",
  "productQuantity": 3,
  "productName": "Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple",
  "productPrice": "7",
  "productCategory": "Fruits & Vegetables",
  "shopId": "10375",
  "shopName": "Dubori",
  "shopDelivery": "1",
  "delivery": 1,
  "variant": "{\"id\":400002,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/83c7dc09da8eceae96fd9bcbd819e43b.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":7,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple      Rs.7\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400002\"}"
}, {
  "productId": "400006",
  "productQuantity": "1",
  "productName": "Apple (Kashmiri)",
  "productPrice": "33",
  "productCategory": "Fruits & Vegetables",
  "shopId": "10375",
  "shopName": "Dubori",
  "shopDelivery": "1",
  "delivery": 1,
  "variant": "{\"id\":400006,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/07e8be62843d3c9145d572df70fe06d4.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":33,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Apple (Kashmiri)      Rs.33\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400006\"}"
}]
```

Right now it has only two elements but there shall be more

Comment: Please post the full code. One line is not enough to understand the situation

Comment: theres no other code...i mean i have this array called cart but it always removes the last element

Comment: I have updated the array above

Comment: well your cart array might have just 2 elements in it and  `cart.splice(1, 1);` removes one element at index 1 which is the second one.

Comment: right now it has two elements but I have tried with 7-8 elements its still removing the last

Comment: @hearty use cart.slice(1);  will remove first element always

Comment: I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1as8Lu4/) and attempted to reproduce your problem. It works there flawlessly. I am voting to close this question as [it is about an issue that can no longer be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @hearty Please mark my answer as correct

Comment: doesn't help @SheshankS.

Comment: @hearty how? What do you need then.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to learn more about the splice function.

Here's a quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
// inserts at 1st index position
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'June']

months.splice(4, 1, 'May');
// replaces 1 element at 4th index
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May']
```

So in your case, this code snippet might help you. Remember, just do `splice(index, 0, item)` 0 if you want to insert.

```js
var array = [{
  "productId": "400002",
  "productQuantity": 3,
  "productName": "Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple",
  "productPrice": "7",
  "productCategory": "Fruits & Vegetables",
  "shopId": "10375",
  "shopName": "Dubori",
  "shopDelivery": "1",
  "delivery": 1,
  "variant": "{\"id\":400002,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/83c7dc09da8eceae96fd9bcbd819e43b.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":7,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple      Rs.7\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400002\"}"
}, {
  "productId": "400006",
  "productQuantity": "1",
  "productName": "Apple (Kashmiri)",
  "productPrice": "33",
  "productCategory": "Fruits & Vegetables",
  "shopId": "10375",
  "shopName": "Dubori",
  "shopDelivery": "1",
  "delivery": 1,
  "variant": "{\"id\":400006,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/07e8be62843d3c9145d572df70fe06d4.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":33,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Apple (Kashmiri)      Rs.33\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400006\"}"
}];
console.log(array);

array.splice(1, 0, ["hi"]);
console.log(array);
```

This line `array.splice(1, 0, ["hi"]);` inserts ["hi"] at the position 1.

however, `array.splice(1, 1, ["hi"]);` replaces the thing in position 1 with ["hi"]

`array.slice(1)` removes the first element

Answer (score 0):

Just use `arr.slice(startingIndex, endingIndex)`.

If you do not specify the endingIndex, it returns all the items starting from the index provided.

In your case `arr=arr.slice(1)`.

```js
var cart=[{"productId":"400002","productQuantity":3,"productName":"Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple","productPrice":"7","productCategory":"Fruits & Vegetables","shopId":"10375","shopName":"Dubori","shopDelivery":"1","delivery":1,"variant":"{\"id\":400002,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/83c7dc09da8eceae96fd9bcbd819e43b.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":7,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Annadata Organic Brinjal Long Purple      Rs.7\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400002\"}"},{"productId":"400006","productQuantity":"1","productName":"Apple (Kashmiri)","productPrice":"33","productCategory":"Fruits & Vegetables","shopId":"10375","shopName":"Dubori","shopDelivery":"1","delivery":1,"variant":"{\"id\":400006,\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\\\/doorhopperimg\\\/products\\\/07e8be62843d3c9145d572df70fe06d4.jpg\",\"quantity\":\"250gm\",\"price\":33,\"afterTax\":null,\"stock\":-2,\"description\":\"Apple (Kashmiri)      Rs.33\\\/250gm\",\"barcode\":\"10375400006\"}"}];

var output=cart.slice(1);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: just use arr.slice(1) if you want to remove first element